# iOS Image View doesn't show the image on emulator

Tags: ios, uiimageview

Beginner iOS here, I am trying to make a splash screen, the image shows up in the editor but not on an emulator. I placed an image view and set the image in the top right corner. How do I make it show in the emulator?

[image: with constraints]
[image]

Edit: Tried playing with different constraints, still no image but now the text is centered right so that's a plus

Comment: Are you running it with all those red constraints?  Red constraints are conflicting (bad).  You'll want to make sure those are resolved before trying to run.

Comment: Did you want to make it in the center?

Comment: Fixed the red, and yeah, center would be nice but at this point I'm just trying to make it show up at all

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't have any constraints on your storyboard.  Follow these images, this will get you some automatic constraints that should work for testing and giving you an idea of how they look and work.  As you get better do some tutorials on Auto-layout and learn how to add and edit these constraints yourself.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I tried this but the image still isn't showing, the text is nice and centered though

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display the image in the center of your viewController, you can simply add the two constraints for that: "center horizontally in container" and "center vertically in container". But before that clear the old constraints then add the width and height to your image then add those two constraints to center it. Check [this](http://www.appcoda.com/introduction-auto-layout/)

Answer (score 0):

There is a good chance the image is not getting copied into your bundle then, so it is not available to display.

1. Select your app target build
2. Build phases
3. Copy bundle resources

Make sure your image appears under Copy bundle resources.

[image]